# Media Temple migrated to new server and website crashed

Tags: database, migration, zend-framework, php-pdo

I am not a web developer.  Looking for some insight.

Media Temple recently migrated the domain to a new server and my website crashed.  They have not provided any details of why it happened or what they are doing to fix it.

**These are the errors showing:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused**

```
3 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
Exception #2 (PDOException): PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
```

Could anyone help? Thank you

Comment: Is your new website running now?

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the MySql configuration which changed after your hosting provider moved to new server or it was caused by your server running out of memory.

Ask them to check:

1. The following MySql config (maybe need to compare with the old config if needed) for you:

- max_allowed_packet
- wait_timeout

2. Check memory usage, maybe increasing swap file size helps resolve your issue.

And tell them to take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away